# I am trying to create an writable nested serializer in django, but can't use post method properly

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

So I am trying to create a serializer that shows me the whole object of the other model that is linked by a ForeignKey with the model I am working with my GET woks good, but I can only post by creating a new Country not with an actual existing one,
so here are my two models, Model 1

```
class CountryName1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

the other model, Model 2

```
class TeslaModel1(models.Model):
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    origin = models.ForeignKey(CountryName1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='teslamodels')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name
```

My serializers are like this

```
class CountryNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CountryName1
        fields = ['name']


class TeslaModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    origin = CountryNameSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = TeslaModel1
        fields = ['model_name', 'price', 'origin']

        def create(self, validated_data):
            origin_data = validated_data.pop('origin')
            country_model = CountryName1.objects.create(**origin_data)
            dataitem = TeslaModel1.objects.create(origin=country_model, 
            **validated_data)

            return dataitem
```

Here are my views:

```
class TeslaModelListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = TeslaModel1.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeslaModelSerializer


class CountryNameListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = CountryName1.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountryNameSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any other person who may have the same question,
here how I fixed it
Create 2 serializers one for POST and one for GET instead of only TeslaModelSerializer

```
class TeslaModelReadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    origin = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = TeslaModel1
        fields = ['model_name', 'price', 'origin']

    def get_origin(self, tesla_model):
        return CountryNameSerializer(tesla_model.origin).data

class TeslaModelWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = TeslaModel1
        fields = ['model_name', 'price', 'origin']
```

And then our view would change like this

```
class TeslaModelListCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = TeslaModel1.objects.all()
    read_serializer_class = TeslaModelReadSerializer
    write_serializer_class = TeslaModelWriteSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return self.read_serializer_class
        return self.write_serializer_class
```

-Here I supposed that we have only POST and GET but you can modify your view for your needs for other methods like DELETE,PUT...

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, just change this `TeslaModelSerializer`

```
class TeslaModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    origin = CountryNameSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TeslaModel1
        fields = ['model_name', 'price', 'origin']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        origin_data = validated_data.pop('origin')
        tesla = TeslaModel1.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for data in origin_data:
            CountryName1.objects.create(**data)
        return tesla
```

Check this out [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) for more.